# Error in Glassfish 5: Using deprecated META-INF/services property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Used property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory instead

Tags: java, soap, glassfish

Después de instalar la última versión de Glassfish (la 5.0), nuestro servicio SOAP está imprimiendo el siguiente error para todas las peticiones y respuestas:

> Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard
>   property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property
>   javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.

Hemos revisado la definición del servicio pero no tenemos ninguna configuración en META-INF para la librería. Por consiguiente, no entendemos qué produce el mensaje.

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta, o de lo contrario esperar a que alguien más la responda.

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le puede servir:

Hemos conseguido evitar el mensaje siguiendo las mismas instrucciones que se indican en la respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798366/how-do-i-find-out-which-jaxp-implementation-is-in-use-and-where-it-was-loaded-fr para  la implementación de DocumentBuilderFactory. Donde se hace referencia a la documentación oficial JAXP [Java EE]:

> When an application wants to create a new JAXP DocumentBuilderFactory instance, it calls the staic method  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(). This causes a search for the name of a concrete subclass of  DocumentBuilderFactory using the following order:
>
> 1. The value of a system property like javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory if it exists and is accessible.
> 2. The contents of the file $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/jaxp.properties if it exists.
> 3. The Jar Service Provider discovery mechanism specified in the Jar File Specification. A jar file can have a resource (i.e. an embedded file) such as META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory containing the name of the concrete class to instantiate.
> 4. The fallback platform default implementation.

Siguiendo los pasos, hemos creado el archivo META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory indicando la implementación por defecto a utilizar:

com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl

Y con esto ya ha dejado de aparecer el mensaje.

Comment: Me alegra que solucionaras tu problema. Podrias explicar mejor la respuesta aqui? Asi si la respuesta que enlazas desapareciera, la tuya tendria toda la inforamcion necesaria para futuros users. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo